# React Native Timer UI

Tags: react-native, timer

I'm looking for a component who display the picker, for a timer. I'm using react-native-datetimepicker but doesn't solve my problem. Need only that timer picker. It's difficult to find in Google because the results are irrelevant.

Comment: please provide more details because there are many components available like https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker#readme you can use it

Comment: Don't need to select time. I want to select like duration. e.g. 20minutes, 30 min,  1 h 15min .....

Comment: Try using https://github.com/flurmbo/react-duration-picker#readme

Comment: Thanks! That's what I need. It works

Comment: I have answered as well

Answer (score 0):

Try using [react-duration-picker](https://github.com/flurmbo/react-duration-picker#readme)

```
const onChange = duration => {
  const { hours, minutes, seconds } = duration;
  setState({ hours, minutes, seconds });
};

return (
  <Modal open={isOpen}>
    <DurationPicker
      onChange={onChange}
      initialDuration={{ hours: 1, minutes: 2, seconds: 3 }}
      maxHours={5}
    />
    <button onClick={closeModal} />
  </Modal>
);
```

Example code [Here](https://github.com/flurmbo/react-duration-picker/blob/master/example/App.jsx)